# distinct or group by doesn't work well

Tags: hbase, distinct, varchar, apache-phoenix

i have problem with distinct and aggregation functions in phoenix on hbase. 
i have some ip in my table. some of them are repetitive. when i use

```
select *,
```

the query return all ips but when i use

```
distinct or count(1) and group by
```

To remove the duplicate IPs but in result some IPs totally deleted and there are not in result. i save my ips in varchar column in hbase and query on hbase with phoenix.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: you may want to create a secondary index and retry, you may have better results then

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by deleting and recreate view in phoenix.